# Show/Hide text box based on selection from multiple drop down boxes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with a row of drop down menus with the values 1 -5. When the user selects a value less than three on any box, I want a pop up box to appear underneath the table.  The popup only needs to appear once for any amount of drop downs that have a value less than 3, not once for every value less than 3. The code works when I assign the `<select id='purpose'>`, but it will only work on the first `<select>`. How do I make it work for all of them?

using this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#purpose').on('change', function() {
if ( this.value < 3)
{
$("#business").show();
}
else
{
$("#business").hide();
}
});
});
```

Snippet of the HTML:

```
                                      <td>
                                     <select id='purpose'>
                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                     </select>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                     <select id='purpose'>
                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                     </select>

...

                                 </table>
                                 <div style='display:none;' id='business'>                                    
                                    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' placeholder="You gave a rating of less than 3 in one or more categories. Please provide a brief explination as to why." />
                                    <br/>
                                 </div>
```

Comment: Two separate elements can't/shouldn't have the same ID. Classes can be repeated, but ID's shouldn't, especially when they're used for Javascript purposes. You will have to give the second `<select>` and different ID and then make the appropriate changes in your Javascript.

Comment: you can't have two element with same `id`

Comment: Why did you use same id both select?

Answer (score 0):

Each `select` element should be assigned to to the same `class` rather than the same `id`.  Then, the logic can be applied to all classes.

```
<td>  
  <select class="purpose">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>     
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</td>                      
<td>  
  <select class="purpose">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>     
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

And the appropriate selector is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.purpose').on('change', function() {
    if ( this.value < 3) {
      $("#business").show();
    } else {
      $("#business").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have duplicate ids which should be removed.

The popup only needs to appear once for any amount of drop downs that have a value less than 3, not once for every value less than 3. The code works when I assign the , but it will only work on the first . How do I make it work for all of them?

```
If you want the change event for work on both the both select you 
can just attach on select element. This will trigger the code for all
select elements as below.
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').on('change', function() {
if ( this.value < 3)
{
$("#business").show();
}
else
{
$("#business").hide();
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
                                     <select >
                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                     </select>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                     <select>
                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                     </select>

...

                                 </table>
                                 <div style='display:none;' id='business'>                                    
                                    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' placeholder="You gave a rating of less than 3 in one or more categories. Please provide a brief explination as to why." />
                                    <br/>
                                 </div>
```

Comment: Awesome! This is almost 100% working. When I set a value to less than 3, the box pops up like it should. But when I select a different box to be greater than three, the box goes away, which it shouldn't.

Comment: yes you need to handle that in this handler..which you can do easily..just check other box value as well and do the logic